# Threads processing a batch job in servlet enviornment

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, threadpool, batch-processing

I have a Spring-MVC, Hibernate, (Postgres 9 db) Web app. An admin user can send in a request to process nearly 200,000 records (each record collected from various tables via joins). Such operation is requested on a weekly or monthly basis (OR whenever the data reaches to a limit of around 200,000/100,000 records). On the database end, i am correctly implementing batching.

- PROBLEM: Such a long running request holds up the server thread and that causes the the normal users to suffer.
- REQUIREMENT: The high response time of this request is not an issue. Whats required is not make other users suffer because of this time consuming process.
- MY SOLUTION:

  Implementing threadpool using Spring taskExecutor abstraction. So i can initialize my threadpool with say 5 or 6 threads and break the 200,000 records into smaller chunks say of size 1000 each. I can queue in these chunks. To further allow the normal users to have a faster db access, maybe I can make every runnable thread sleep for 2 or 3 secs.
  Advantages of this approach i see is: Instead of executing a huge db interacting request in one go, we have a asynchronous design spanning over a larger time. Thus behaving like multiple normal user requests.

Can some experienced people please give their opinion on this?
I have also read about implementing the same beahviour with a Message Oriented Middleware like JMS/AMQP OR Quartz Scheduling. But frankly speaking, i think internally they are also gonna do the same thing i.e making a thread pool and queueing in the jobs. So why not go with the Spring taskexecutors instead of adding a completely new infrastructure in my web app just for this feature?

Please share your views on this and let me know if there is other better ways to do this?
Once again: the time to completely process all the records in not a concern, whats required is that normal users accessing the web app during that time should not suffer in any way.

Comment: How are the jobs structured? Is it one big stored procedure or are you  going through an ORM? Please elaborate this "on the database end, I am correctly implementing batch"?

Comment: Its handled via the ORM and not with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parallelize the tasks and wait for all of them to finish before returning the call. For this, you want to use [ExecutorCompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) which is available in Java standard since 5.0

In short, you use your container's service locator to create an instance of ExecutorCompletionService

```
ExecutorCompletionService<List<MyResult>> queue = new ExecutorCompletionService<List<MyResult>>(executor);

// do this in a loop
queue.submit(aCallable);

//after looping 
queue.take().get(); //take will block till all threads finish
```

If you do not want to wait then, you can process the jobs in the background without blocking the current thread but then you will need some mechanism to inform the client when the job has finished. That can be through JMS or if you have an ajax client then, it can poll for updates.

Quartz also has a job scheduling mechanism but, Java provides a standard way.

EDIT:
I might have misunderstood the question. If you do not want a faster response but rather you want to throttle the CPU, use this approach

You can make an inner class like this PollingThread where batches containing java.util.UUID for each job and the number of PollingThreads are defined in the outer class. This will keep going forever and can be tuned to keep your CPUs free to handle other requests

```
 class PollingThread implements Runnable {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void run(){
                Thread.currentThread().setName("MyPollingThread");
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (incomingList) {
                            if (incomingList.size() == 0) {
                                // incoming is empty, wait for some time
                            } else {
                                //clear the original
                                list = (LinkedHashSet<UUID>) 
                                        incomingList.clone();
                                incomingList.clear();
                            }
                        }

                        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                            processJobs(list);
                        }
                        // Sleep for some time
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            //ignore
                        }
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        //ignore                    
                    }
                }
           }
    }
```

Comment: Even i got confused at first! So you r saying that creating such a thread will be good. If this is true, then i think instead of managing the thread life cycle urself, y not use threadpools like java executors or Spring Taskexecutor abstraction? Am i going the right way?

Comment: I prefer to have a tighter control over my jobs and this gives me exactly that. Also, I prefer to use the standard way of doing things and avoid using a framework unless I understand it very well. If you are comfortable with Spring, then use it but I suspect that all Spring will do is provide you with a pool of Executors. You will still have to divide a big job into smaller batches, schedule them to run, implement the Callable interface and process the result. Launching your own thread just takes a small amount of additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Huge-db-operations are usually triggered at wee hours, where user traffic is pretty less. (Say something like 1 Am to 2 Am.. ) Once you find that out, you can simply schedule a job to run at that time. Quartz can come in handy here, with time based triggers. (Note: Manually triggering a job is also possible.)

The processed result could now be stored in different table(s). (I'll refer to it as *result tables*) Later when a user wants this result, the db operations would be against these *result tables* which have minimal records and hardly any joins would be involved.

> instead of adding a completely new infrastructure in my web app just for this feature?

Quartz.jar is ~ 350 kb and adding this dependency shouldn't be a problem. Also note that there's no reason this need to be as a web-app. These few classes that do [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) could be placed in a standalone module.The request from the web-app needs to only fetch from the *result tables*

All these apart, if you already had a master-slave db model(discuss on that with your dba) then you could do the huge-db operations with the slave-db rather than the master, which normal users would be pointed to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Scheduling as i see is not involved in this as it is on the discretion of the Admin user. Moreover, as far as i know, Quartz will also maintain a threadpool. Can you please tell what aditional benefits can be obtained that java executors dont provide?